# Temporarily Use a Different Version of a Package to Resolve Unmet Dependency

Tags: apt, dependencies

How can I temporarily use a different version of a package so that I can install another package that depends on it? Or is it not possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Synaptic to lock a version, or force it (in case you keep several versions). These options are in the "Package" menu. I understand "force" is the one applicable in your case. This link may be instructive and has screenshots as well: http://techfrp.blogspot.com/2010/12/tip-how-to-force-and-lock-version.html

Comment: So, it's possible to install many versions of the same package with Synaptic? Is that it?

Comment: As long as you use just one of them, which will be either the latest, or the one you force.

Answer (score 0):

No, APT get doesn't get confused by dependencies. Also, for some reason they depends on a specific version. `apt-get` won't allow you to do this. Maybe `dpkg` but again **the dependencies exist for a VERY GOOD reason**.

Comment: So what do you propose to do in such situations? E.g. I would like to use CUDA on my optimus laptop, which requires a package version, that would break my graphics.

Comment: @cuichi literally and from the amount of information you have provided me? *Suck it up* then fix it myself or wait for the developers to fix their stuff.

Comment: I just provided an example. I was asking what you would propose as a SOLUTION to the question - which we have now. DIY or SIU.

Comment: @cuichi ok, seems that we are missing the point here. OP is asking if it can be done: *can install another package that depends on it? Or is it not possible to do that?* My answer: NO.